# Express routing fails to get static files

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express 4.9.4, I cannot get a static file from the server. There is a folder named public and it has a file called test.js in it.
I have tried;

```
var express = require('express'),
    morgan = require('morgan');
var app = express();
var port = 1338;

app.use(morgan('dev')); // log every request to the console
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public' ));
app.listen(port);
```

and I have tried;

```
var express = require('express'),
morgan = require('morgan');

var app = express();
var port = 1338;

app.use(morgan('dev')); // log every request to the console
var router = express.Router();
router.get(express.static(__dirname + '/public' ));
app.listen(port);
```

The server runs and morgan logs the request but I cannot get a file from the public directory

```
myurl.com/test.js
```

returns 404

Comment: `__dirname` is the directory in which your Node script lives. So `public/test.js` needs to exist relative to that directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
  app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Comment: app.use(express.static(app.root + '/public', {maxAge: 86400000}));

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
app.use(express.static(app.root + '/public', {maxAge: 86400000}));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually the version of express. The package.json had '~4.0.0', when that was changed to 'latest' and "npm install" re-run the problem resolved itself.